# Create setup for web application (PHP)

Tags: php, windows-services

I developed a php web application in windows. As you know there is two service needed to do this; APACHE and MYSQL. 
But my application will be hosted in custom computers, possibl no apache and no mysql in it. So I need a windows setup that install these services and also check if they are already exist and running.

Its my first time face with this, so please be as clear as possible on advices and examples. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows environment, the simplest way is to install [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/). To do this in an automated way, you'll need an install script (for quiet install for example). Check the website for details.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I will do it, thank you